# Akka-http: Accept and Content-type handling

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm trying out Akka-http and hopefully someone can shed light on a the following questions:

1. How does one create different routes based on the accept: header in the request? For example, i want one code path to handle "json" and one to handle "xml" requests (with default to "json" if header is missing)
2. In cases where I don't want the contentType to be inferred, how do i specify it? For example, in the code below I try to run the json through compactPrint() but this changes it to a string, hence "text/plain". I want to override that and tell the client it's still json.

My code is something like this;

```
...
path("api") {
          get {
              complete {
                getStuff.map[ToResponseMarshallable] {
                  case Right(r) if r.isEmpty => List[String]().toJson.compactPrint
                  case Right(r) => r.toJson.compactPrint
                  case Left(e) => BadRequest -> e
                }
              }
          }
        }
...
```

The response in this case is text/plain, since compactPrint creates a string.
criticism very welcome. ;)

Comment: To make use of akka-http's automatic content negotiation feature you need to provide a marshaller for your source type that can marshal to several content-types. You can use `Marshaller.oneOf` to compose different marshallers where each marshaller knows how to marshal to just one content-type. Have you seen the documentation about marshaller at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/common/marshalling.html#Custom_Marshallers?

Comment: Thanks. I did end up going this route.

Comment: @jrudolph Link is dead

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/marshalling.html#custom-marshallers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define Content Type as follows,

```
complete {
           HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`), """{"id":"1"}"""))
         }
```

You can create your custom directive as,

```
  def handleReq(json: String) = {
    (get & extract(_.request.acceptedMediaRanges)) {
      r =>
        val encoding: MediaRange =
          r.intersect(myEncodings).headOption
            .getOrElse(MediaTypes.`application/json`)
        complete {
          // check conditions here
         // HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(encoding.specimen, json)) //
        }
    }
  }
```

and use the directive in route as

```
val route = path("api"){ handleReq(json) }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just hoping for a directive to do a rejection based on the header, not to encompass the actual processing. But anyway, I ended up implementing marshallers which automatically take care of serializing to XML or JSON, so I don't need this approach anymore. But thank you for your help,it helped me get past my frustration, and it is one way of implementing things. So I'll accept the answer.

Comment: here better use 
ContentTypes.`application/json` 
instead of 
ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the accepted answer doesn't work anymore with akka-http v10.0.3.

This works though :

```
// the encodings I want, in the order of preference
val myEncodings = Seq(MediaRange(`application/xml`),MediaRange( `application/json`))

...
path("api") {
          (get & extract(_.request.headers)){ requestHeaders =>
              val mediaTypeNegotiator = new MediaTypeNegotiator(requestHeaders)
              val encoding = mediaTypeNegotiator
                     .acceptedMediaRanges
                     .intersect(myEncodings)
                     .headOption
                     .getOrElse(MediaRange(`application/json`))
              complete {
                     // check "encoding" here and make decision.
              }
          }
        }
...
```

you could also do

```
val myEncodings = Seq(MediaRange(`application/xml`),MediaRange( `application/json`))

path("api") {
      (get & extract(_.request.headers)){ requestHeaders =>
        complete {
          val mediaTypeNegotiator = new MediaTypeNegotiator(requestHeaders)
          if(mediaTypeNegotiator.accept(MediaTypes.`application/xml`)) {
            // respond with xml
          } else if(mediaTypeNegotiator.accept(MediaTypes.`application/json`)) {
            // respond with json
          } else {
            // respond with json by default or reject properly :
            reject(UnsupportedRequestContentTypeRejection(Set(MediaTypes.`application/xml`, MediaTypes.`application/json`)))
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A potential answer for question #1 seems to be this, but I'd like to do it via a custom directive or or something more elegant. Unfortunately the documentation for Akka-Http custom directives seems to be missing.

```
// the encodings I want, in the order of preference
val myEncodings = Seq(MediaRange(`application/xml`),MediaRange( `application/json`))

    ...
    path("api") {
              (get & extract(_.request.acceptedMediaRanges)){  
                  r => 
                    val encoding = 
                      r.intersect(myEncodings).headOption
                         .getOrElse(MediaRange(`application/json`))
                  complete {
                         // check "encoding" here and make decision.
                  }
              }
            }
    ...
```

Hoping someone can provide something cleaner.

Comment: I updated the answer, you could check, is it what u want.