# Set Content-Type header

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a problem with akka-http.
The `Content-Type` headers default value is `text/plain`. I am trying to set `application/json` value like this:

```
val routes = 
  respondWithHeader(headers.`Content-Type`(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`))) {
    // ...
    // all api routes
    // ...
  }
```

But this doesn't work. `Content-Type` is still `text/plain`.

**UPD**
I am **NOT** reading clients `Content-Type` header. I am trying to send another from default `Content-Type` header from server.

**UPD2**
For instance:

```
import JsonProtocol.entityFormat
//...
(get & path("api" / "entities")) {
  complete(getAllEntities)
}
```

`getAllEntities` returns a list of entities from `DB` as `Future[Entity]`.
`Entity` is just a model:

```
case class Entity(foo: Int, bar: String)
```

`EntityFormat` looks like:

```
object JsonProtocol extends spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val entityFormat = jsonFormat2(Entity)
}
```

Finally cast `Future` to ResponseMarshallable:

```
implicit def entity2ResponseMarshallable(entityF: Future[Entity]): ToResponseMarshallable =
  entityF map (_.toJson.toString())
```

Comment: Can you try this: respondWithHeader(RawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Akka-http: Accept and Content-type handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187858/akka-http-accept-and-content-type-handling)

Comment: @tea-addict the same result

Comment: @Astrid I dont think so. I have tons routes and tons of tons `complete` methods. I dont want to modify each of them. I want to set header once.

Comment: It'd be good to see an example of one of those methods - usually akka-http auto-detects the content type and sets it to application/json if you're returning a JSON object. Content-Type generally gets special handling and, it looks like, can't be set as a header - see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html#http-headers

Comment: @Astrid Typical complete method sends message to the `akka-actor` via `ask` or `?` wich runs DB request via `slick` and serialize result via `spray-json`.

Comment: The bit I'd like to see is "serialize result via `spray-json`" and the construction of the `HttpEntity` object used in the response. Basically, if you're returning JSON objects then `Content-Type application/json` should be set automatically, and you're probably going to have more luck figuring out why it's not than trying to override your `Content-Type` header globally - which, according to the docs, is likely not possible.

Comment: @Astrid added UPD2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulling together the discussion in comments with an actual solution:

If you remove `.toString` from your `entity2ResponseMarshallable` method, so simply have

```
implicit def entity2ResponseMarshallable(
      entityF: Future[Entity]): ToResponseMarshallable =
    entityF map (_.toJson)
```

you should get the correct content type headers in your server response.

This is how akka-http wants to handle the `Content-Type` header - it sets it automatically depending on what marshaller it ends up using. String, which you had before, translates to `text/plain`.

As for your original question, I don't believe changing the `Content-Type` header manually is possible at that point. As per the [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html#http-headers),

> The Content-Type of an HTTP message is modeled as the contentType field of the HttpEntity. The Content-Type header therefore doesn’t appear in the headers sequence of a message. Also, a Content-Type header instance that is explicitly added to the headers of a request or response will not be rendered onto the wire and trigger a warning being logged instead!

So in order to set the content-type manually, you have to override it in the `HttpEntity` instance as per the other question I originally linked - in order to do it on a route level you'd have to redefine the `HttpEntity` contained in your `HttpResponse` after the fact which I'm not sure is possible, and which doesn't sound like a good idea in any case.